# Can we write Middlewares for Node.JS without using any framework?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am new in Node.JS development. I have learned to write middlewares for Express in NodeJS. But I would like to know how can we write a middleware without using a frameworks ? Does Middlewares are specific to express ?

Comment: Middleware is a feature of Express. To write middleware without a framework implies that you would first need to write your own framework (one which supports the concept of middleware). Being new to Node, you probably wouldn't want to do this :-)

Comment: Thank you, I got the point.